# STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING not working for me in Xcode 3.2.5

Tags: xcode

The STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING build setting in Xcode 3.2.5 isn't working for me.

My source code, including the .strings files, are UTF-8. I want the built application to have the .strings files stored as UTF-16.

The Project | Edit Active Target "Build" tab (there's only one target) is set up as follows:

"Convert copied Files" (APPLY_RULES_IN_COPY_FILES) is checked.
  "Strings file Output Encoding" (STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING) is set to UTF-16.

But the .strings files in the .app that is built are still UTF-8.

Am I wrong about the purpose of STRINGS_FILE_OUTPUT_ENCODING? Or am I doing it wrong? Or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else with this problem:

This was caused by not properly registering the .strings files in Xcode as being for translations. The structure of the localization folders was wrong. When I corrected the structure and properly registered the .strings files for localization, everything worked.

(This was a project I inherited.)